# Can't get Cygwin to install

Tags: cygwin, installation

I am trying to install Cygwin on someone's computer. During the setup, when
the window with the websites to get cygwin from shows up, it's empty. I tried
typing some links, that I know work (tried it on another machine) and they don't work - getting an error message. (something about not being to get the .ini ... )

Any ideas?

Comment: Fix your internet connection, if you can't do that you don't need to be installing cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If the list of websites isn't being populated, Setup.exe is unable to get to the internet. Make sure you are connected (including checking your Proxy settings) and try again.